# Force CSS to not inherit any properties

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a component which will work in different sites. The problem is that it inherits the existing style sheets of the site. This causes a huge mess in my component.

Am wondering if there is a way to force it to not inherit any properties whatsoever of the main site.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**

I cannot iFrame the content. My component will cease to function then.

Comment: Without iframes, you will likely be stuck overriding all CSS styles defined for your component. The inheritance is what it's supposed to do, after all. It's what the "C" in CSS is all about.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- iFrame the content. This way it's a window into another site... not the site itself.
- Define your own inline styles that will never be overwritten.
- Define class names that are difficult or impossible to overwrite accidentally. Don't use generic terms like 'content' or 'article'... instead use 'myverydifficulttoconflictwithcssclassname'. You get the idea.

Comment: #2 doesn't work very well if he's on multiple sites. He'd have to reset every property on every single style definition.

Comment: I use option 3 with emails that will appear in webmail apps. I prefix all classnames like mdjtnrfu_content, mdjtnrfu_header, etc.. It aint pretty but it's generally the least problematic solution. It won't help you for selectors on tags, :first-child, etc... I think CSS needs namespaces (maybe that's a CSS3 thing?)

Comment: #3 am already doing. But some sites have stupid CSS like tags affecting all TD, DIV etc.

Comment: Sounds like #1 is the only thing that will give you reliable results. I just hope you don't need the content to grow

Comment: #2 works via specificity principles where inline styles are worth 1000. You'd have to be *ultra* specific for a widget to overwrite that. Consider Google Adwords.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `reset.css` file which sets every property of every element to the default with the `!important` declaration, and then always use `!important` in your real style, but that's a big hack. If your "component" is being inserted in other sites, have you considered `iframes`? You'd get your own CSS scoping.